# Android using shared preferences to check on first run

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-sharedpreferences

Hi I'm trying to detect whether my app has been opened for the first time. If it has, I need to run an activity and once it's opened for the second time it should not show it again.

This is my code:

fragment:

```java
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TutorialFeaturedActivity.class);
    //startActivity(intent);

    SharedPreferences settings = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0); // Get preferences file (0 = no option flags set)
    boolean firstRun = settings.getBoolean("firstRun", true); // Is it first run? If not specified, use "true"

    if(firstRun) {
        Log.w("onCreate: ","first time" );
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TutorialFeaturedActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit(); // Open the editor for our settings
        editor.putBoolean("firstRun", false); // It is no longer the first run
        editor.apply(); // Save all changed settings
    } else {
        Log.w("onCreate: ","second time");
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    getSpecials();
}
```

But all it does is start the activity and when I start it again it freezes in a white screen but checking the logs it shows like the else statement is constantly running over and over. I'm fairly new to Android so some help or advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: you should use editor.commit(); for saving changes

Comment: May I ask what the use of `getActivity().finish()` is? Thats the difference I see between first and second run. and it might be that this brings you back the the class where you check the first run and you enter an endless loop?!

Comment: When i use editor.commit(); or apply i still get the same result, also the ide tells me i shoudl use apply instead of commit but same issue.

Comment: @Nico i use getActivity().finish(); to end the tutorial activty thats running i forgot to take it out in the question cause it still doesnt fix anything

Comment: Please post all code in this file.

Comment: .commit() and .apply() does the exact same thing. Only difference is apply works asynchronously.

Comment: @thaabitv please check my answer.

Comment: Which Activity is this Fragment attached to? If it's MainActivity, then you're looping through asking it to restart itself ... So what is happening is exactly what you've asked it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences pref = YourActivityName.this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor= pref.edit();
    boolean firstRun = pref.getBoolean("firstRun", true); 
    if(firstRun)
    {
        Log.i("onCreate: ","first time" );
        editor.putBoolean("firstRun",false);
        editor.commit();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TutorialFeaturedActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i("onCreate: ","second time");
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
   // getSpecials();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your activity is looping because within your else statement, you tell it to restart the activity which lands again in the else statement and so on and so on.

Comment: I agree .. something like this is occurring - SharedPreferences is not the problem. It would make sense if the Fragment in the OP code is attached to MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `editor.commit` if `editor.apply` not working

```
editor.putBoolean("firstRun", false); 
editor.apply(); // Save all changed settings
editor.commit(); // Save all changed settings
```

Comment: As mentioned in above comments there is no difference between those two besides Asynchronousity. OP also stated that changing didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I know there is no diff b/w apply and commit

Comment: I think that "no difference" is misleading. editor.commit() save changes immediately while editor.apply() save in background.

Comment: But it does the same function, right? That's what I meant to say

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    SharedPreferences prefs = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (prefs.getBoolean("firstRun", true)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TutorialFeaturedActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstRun", false).commit();
        }
       else
        {
          //do nothing
        }

      getSpecials();
    }
}
```

Comment: this works perfect thanks however when adding it in the next activity that i show a tut screen it does not work the same, anyway to have it work the same in multiple activities??

Answer (score 0):

In else case your starting "MainActivity.class".
Why your loading  MainActivity from the oncreate of MainActivity ?
it will make a loop.

Remove the start activity from else case.

Answer (score 0):

**Please Try this my friend**

```
public class SessionManager {

private static String TAG = SessionManager.class.getSimpleName();

SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
Context _context;

// Shared pref mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

// Shared preferences file name
private static final String PREF_NAME = "ManageRun";

private static final String KEY_IS_RUN = "isRun";


public SessionManager(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

public void setLatest(boolean isRun) {

    editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_RUN, isRun);
    // commit changes
    editor.commit();
    Log.d(TAG, "Manage Version session modified!");
}

public boolean isLatest() {
    return pref.getBoolean(KEY_IS_RUN, true);
}
}
```

**In first Activity Check **

```
private SessionManager session;


session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

if (session.isLatest()) {
    session.setLatest(false);
    Log.w("onCreate: ","first time" );
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TutorialFeaturedActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
else
{
    Log.w("onCreate: ","second time");
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: multiple activities means ?

Comment: i think im having an issue with the code im trying to use the code in another activity too but since the preference is being save in the first run of the one activity it doesnt show in the next one.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private boolean isFirstTime() {
        if (firstTime == null) {
            SharedPreferences mPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("first_time", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            firstTime = mPreferences.getBoolean("firstTime", true);
            if (firstTime) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("firstTime", false);
                editor.commit();
            }
        }
        return firstTime;
    }



 if (isFirstTime()) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, Intro_slider.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();

                } else {
                    final UserFunctions uf = new UserFunctions();
                    if (uf.isUserLoggedIn(SplashActivity.this)) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, Social_Login_Activity.class);
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
```

Try this code.